# How do I declare constants in Objective-C in a namespace?

Tags: objective-c, constants

In Java I'd go

```
class SettingKeys
{
    static String USERNAME = "username";
    static String PASSWORD = "password";
}
```

and then use it going

```
username = settings.get(SettingKeys.USERNAME);
```

What do I do in Objective-C?

Answer (score 6):

Objective-C doesn't have namespaces. You could make constants returned in a class method, but that's rarely done; rather, you just declare constants in the global context, and perhaps prefix the name so that there aren't naming conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

The general way of doing it in Objective-C is to use a `typedef`'d `enum`:

```
typedef enum
{
    MyClassConstant1,
    MyClassConstant2,
    MyClassConstant3
} MyClassConstant;

@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    MyClassConstant _something;
}

@end
```

Of course this only works for constant integer values; for strings you generally do:

```
extern NSString * const MyClassString1;
```

... etc.

Comment: so I might as well go #define KEY @"blah"?

Comment: @RogerWernersson Well depends; one advantage of using a fixed set of `NSString` objects is that you can do comparison using `==` rather `isEqualToString` which can improve performance...